# How to get the value written beside object in php

Tags: php

I have an API call that returns the following object:

```
{#177 ▼
  +"_links": {#180 ▶}
  +"name": "EC Flamengo"
  +"code": null
  +"shortName": "Flamengo"
  +"squadMarketValue": null
  +"crestUrl": null
}
```

My question is, how to get the value 177 from that object? I tried object->id and object->key but no luck there.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Did you feed it through `json_decode()` first? `print_r()` the variable you assigned the object to and see what it actually contains

Comment: What command are you using to output the data?

Comment: the object data is not clear...what's those arrow can u format it a bit like using print_r() to print the object to your screen.

Comment: I am using dd() helper function in laravel.

Answer (score 1):

This is not formatted as a valid object, so it's really difficult for us to say how PHP sees your data.

Suppose your data is assigned to `$data`. Do the following:

```
var_export($data);
```

This will print the object structure in the way PHP would reconstruct it if it had to.  This will make it easy for you to see what you're working with.